# How do i fetch a single value from serialize()

Tags: jquery

I have a form and i fetch the values of form using jQuery `.serialize();` for example to fetch the form data i use the following.

```
var formData = $('form').serialize();
```

now the variable formData holds the following value.

```
subcategoryname=aaaa&prefix=AA&categoryid=1
```

from the above string i want to fetch only the value of `categoryid` i.e 1 here, how do i do it using jQuery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you should use .serializeArray() to make it as an object which makes it much easier to access.

Comment: Yes, however it cannot be submitted via ajax in that form.

Comment: It can be submitted via ajax form. Atleast I have done it so always. Quote from jquery docs: Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

Answer (score 4):

you can parse it by splitting the "&" and subsplit each by "="

or take this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/deserialize

Maybe you should access the field before serializing, then you wont need to deSerialize

Comment: yeah, i was just wondering if jQuery provided any native function of doing what i want, other wise i was using `$('form input[name="categoryid"]')` :)

Comment: IMHO second approach is better, it should also fix URL-encoding.

Answer (score 4):

Would it not be easier to use:

`$('input[name=categoryid]').val();`

Or is this not an option?

Comment: i am already using this, i just wanted to know if there is any alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

if you only need one value of your form, why use `.serialize()` ?
You could use [standard selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score -1):

You can access each value using this method :

var firstValue = formData[0].value;

var secondValue = formData[1].value;

var thirdValue = formData[2].value;

.
.
.
etc.